# Django join two models in ListApiView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I listed blog post using django rest api
View.py

```
 class BlogDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
        queryset = models.Blog.objects.all()
        serializer_class = serializers.BlogSerializer
```

models.py

```
  class Blog(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        content = models.TextField()
        content = models.TextField()
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        category_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)



class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.TextField()
    category_title = models.TextField()
```

serializers.py

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'content', 'created_at',)
        model = models.Blog
```

But i want to list the blogs and their sub blogs(category). How to join Category and Blog model?. Here category id are common in two models.

Comment: what is the `Cart` model?

Comment: It was Category Model

Comment: please read model [relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/) in django

Comment: Why do you have `category_id` as a CharField, rather than as a ForeignKey to Category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `category_id` field always references a category, you should make this a foreign key to category. In your example, it looks like it relates to the `category_id` which is a `CharField`. If you want this to be a foreign key to any other field other than the primary key, you can specify the `to_field`. Note that this field will need to be unique on the `Category` model.

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    category_title = models.TextField()

class Blog(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, to_field='category_id', db_column='category_id')
```

From there you can can return any details of a blog's category from the blog object via the foreign key

```py
>>> blog_obj = Blog.objects.first()
>>> category_title = blog_obj.category.category_title
```